# Mostrar a quantidade de cada letra do alfabeto em uma String

Tags: java, string, char, ascii, caracteres

Estou fazendo um exercício em Java onde o usuário entra com uma frase. Após isso, tenho que listar quantas letras existem na frase, por exemplo:

Entrada = Daniel Henrique
Saída:

> A = 1 B = 0 C = 0 D = 1 ... Z = 0

Segue código:

```
String frase = "";
int n = 0;
int c = 97;
int letra = 0;
int qtdn = 0;

System.out.print("Frase: ");
frase = leia.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
    while (c <= 122) {
        if (frase.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == (char) c) {
            qtdn++;
        }
        System.out.println((char) c + " = " + qtdn);
        c++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi responder porque não gostei das soluções atuais, apesar de certas. Em geral o pessoal não programa pensando em performance. Em um algoritmo desses que pode ser usado repetidas vezes pode causar grande estrago e depois o pessoal culpa o Java por consumir muita memória. Em uma solução (a a aceita  atualmente) faz uma alocação de *string* sem necessidade, e na outra (a mais votada atualmente) faz duas alocações, o que gera pressão no *garbage collector*, então eu pego cada caractere localmente e o manipulo, eliminando as alocações desnecessárias. Pode parecer que tem mais processamento, mas vai olhar o que está por dentro dessas funções usadas, está usando até 3 laços sem nem se dar conta:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String frase = "Daniel Henrique";
        int[] quantidades = new int[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
            if (frase.charAt(i) > 64 && frase.charAt(i) < 91) quantidades[frase.charAt(i) - 65]++;
            if (frase.charAt(i) > 96 && frase.charAt(i) < 123) quantidades[frase.charAt(i) - 97]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidades.length; i++) System.out.println((char)(i + 65) + " => " + quantidades[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/df6DGH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CountLettersjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CountLetters.java).

Comment: Essas duas verificações (de 65 a 90 && 97 a 122) é para verificar as maiúsculas e minúsculas certo?

Answer (score 3):

O que você pode fazer é inverter a ordem dos laços, ou seja para cada letra do alfabeto você conta na frase quantas existem, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
        String frase = "Daniel Henrique";
        int n = 0;
        int c = 97;
        int letra = 0;

        System.out.print("Frase: ");
        frase = leia.nextLine();

        while (c <= 122) {
            int qtdn = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
                if (frase.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == (char) c) {
                    qtdn++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println((char) c + " = " + qtdn);
            c++;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa fazer um *loop* dentro de outro, pois isso é bem ineficiente: para cada caractere da `String`, você quer compará-lo com cada uma das 26 letras, então no final você estará fazendo N * 26 iterações (sendo `N` o tamanho da `String`).

Dá para fazer tudo isso percorrendo a `String` uma única vez. Basta criar um array contendo a contagem de cada letra, e ir atualizando-o conforme percorre a `String`.

Depois você faz outro *loop* para mostrar as quantidades de cada letra:

```
String frase = "Daniel Henrique";
int[] quantidades = new int[26];

for (char c : frase.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
    int indice = c - 65;
    if (indice >= 0 && indice < 26) {
        quantidades[indice] += 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < quantidades.length; i++) {
    char letra = (char) (i + 65);
    System.out.println(letra + "=" + quantidades[i]);
}
```

Primeiro eu crio um array contendo as quantidades de cada letra, por isso ele tem 26 posições. Eu me aproveito do fato de que em Java, um array de `int` criado desta maneira [já é inicializado com zero em todas as posições](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154297) (o que é justamente o que precisamos, pois no início a quantidade de qualquer letra é zero, já que eu ainda não iniciei a contagem).

No primeiro `for` eu percorro a `String`. No seu código deu a entender que tanto faz se as letras forem maiúsculas ou minúsculas, então eu estou usando maiúsculas (`toUpperCase()`).

Para cada caractere, eu verifico se ele é uma letra de `A` a `Z` (ao subtrair 65 de um `char`, caso este seja uma letra de `A` a `Z`, o resultado estará entre zero e 25, que é uma posição válida no array de quantidades). Se for, eu somo 1 na respectiva quantidade.

No segundo `for` eu imprimo as letras e suas respectivas quantidades. No fim, eu só percorri a `String` e as quantidades uma vez, totalizando N + 26 iterações (sendo `N` o tamanho da `String`) - bem melhor que fazer um *loop* dentro de outro, o que como já foi dito, gera N * 26 iterações.